# difference between adding braces and not adding braces in for loop in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, nested-loops

Ok so i was working on some programs given in my text book
which is

```
{
    int n,k;
    n=1;
    while(n<=5){
        cout<<"\n";
        for(k=1;k<=n;k++)
        
        
        cout<<k<<" ";
        n++;
    
    }

}
```

the output is[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjoue.png)
but after that when i added braces in for loop it burst

```
 {
    int n,k;
    n=1;
    while(n<=5){
        cout<<"\n";
        for(k=1;k<=n;k++){
        
        
        cout<<k<<" ";
        n++;}
    
    }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dh6mS.png)
SO can anyone explain why this happen's?

Comment: C++ is not Python.  Indentation doesn't mean anything in C++.  If you want two or more lines of code to be influenced by the `for` loop, then braces are required.   Braces are how you do block scope in C++.

Comment: Indentation does nothing in C++ except make the code easier to read.  In C++, scopes are controlled by curly braces.

Comment: If you increase `n`and `k`at the same time, you will always have `k <= n`, and the loop will never finish.

Answer (score 0):

The (simplified) grammar of a for loop is following:

```
for (init ; condition ; iteration) statement
```

Notice that the loop body consists of a single statement. In the first example, that statement is the expression statement

```
cout<<k<<" ";
```

In the second example, that statement is the block statement

```
{
    
    
    cout<<k<<" ";
    n++;}

}
```

This block statement contains more than one expression statement.